# TSN scheduling/routing PYTHON library

Tags: python, algorithm, routes, libraries, scheduling

My question is regarding suggestions for PYTHON libraries about algorithm scheduling mainly, but more specifically about doing scheduling and routing in networks. (Examples of algorithms like: ALAP, ASAP etc. ). My area is TSN (Time-Sensitive Network) and my objective is to design algorithms for scheduling of tasks and finding the routes from point A to B for example.

Here is an example for routing:
[Topology Routing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6U2r.png)

Here is an example for scheduling:
[Small scheduling example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfRbN.png)

Comment: Do you have any constraint?

Comment: No particular constraints, I need to analyze the efficiency of different routing/scheduling algorithms based on their performance ( latency/ queue usage).